# Use the same linq with different table prefixes

Tags: linq-to-sql, prefix, prefixes

I have a webapplication that uses LINQ to connect to a database.
The problem is that I Only have 1 database, and I need a several copy's of the tables, 1 copy / client. Is it possible to make linq use a set of tables acording to their prefex ?

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop the same table to the surface of dbml file and rename the newly added table in dbml to anything you want, that way you can have more than on represenation of single table in linq and you can easily implement whatever you want

I hope I understand your problem correctly